# For loop for assigning colors to a plot python

Tags: python, for-loop, plot, data-visualization

I am working on a for loop to assign numbers to the classes and I am successful in that but I find it hard to simultaneously insert different colors based on the number of classes using the same for loop but I am getting the error :**'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

Below is the code:

```
n_class = 5
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y','k', 'y']
# plotting
for i, c in range(n_class, colors):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], linestyle='--',color=[c], label= 'Class %d' %i )
        

plt.title('Multiclass ROC curve')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive rate')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('Multiclass ROC',dpi=300);
```

Comment: You aren't using `range` correctly.  Its two-argument form is range(low, high).  What you actually want is `for i, c in enumerate(colors):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on this line

```
for i, c in range(n_class, colors):
```

It's pretty simple, all you have to do is to get the length of the list

```
for i, c in range(n_class, len(colors)):
```

But I don't think that's the main error are, because then it will take it as

```
range(5,6)
```

if you want to give all the plots a color you'll need

```
for i in range(len(colors)):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], linestyle='--',color=colors[i], label= 'Class %d' %i )
```